# jquery class list toggle with close when clicking outside element

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

Pretty new to jquery/javascript, but proficient in html/css...

I have a list of siblings with the class .item.  Each is a pin on a map.  I'd like to achieve 3 things:

- Open/close toggle on click, using a class of 'active' which I manipulate with CSS
- When one .item is open, clicking another with close it and also open the new one
- When clicking outside an .item, it will close

I've seen a few examples using IDs, but hopefully I can just use the .item class, or perhaps a parent id - #map.

I've achieved the first point using toggleClass()

```
$('#map .item').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Simplified html:

```
<div id="map">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: sure, html added and link to real site, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood, this should work:

```
$(function () {
    $('#map .item').click(function(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation(); //stops the document click action
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });


    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#map .item').removeClass('active'); //make all inactive
    });
});
```

You can read more about the event bubbling here http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: +1, only thing I'd change is `$(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')`, that way there's only one call to `$(this)`, instead of two

Comment: i knew 'bubbling' might be another issue so thanks for dealing with this too!  nice, plain english code.. thanks :)

Comment: hey, sorry for getting back to this one 5 months after the fact.. another issue is that when you drag the map, the .item closes.. is there a way to differentiate between click and drag? url is the same. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will also work:

```
$("#map .item").click(function(e) {
    var self = $(this)[0];
    $(".item").each(function(index) {
        if (self == $(this)[0])
            $(self).addClass("active");
        else
            $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if (!e.target.id == "map" || !$(e.target).parents("#map").size()) { 
        $(".item").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UT4AG/) example of it working.